# FtpWebRequest not recognizing the URI

Tags: vb.net, ftp

My problem is I can’t seem to get the uri to work. The Error message says “Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined”. Then I get this error message "The URI prefix is not recognized" when I try this line             `Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ftpUri + ":" + port), FtpWebRequest)`

Here’s what I have, and it works perfect when tested in filezilla:
Host: sftp.icecream.com
Username: softserve
Password: chocolate
Port: 22
destination folder: SoManyFlavors

here’s my code:

```
    Private Sub FtpUploadFile(ByVal fileToUpload As String, ByVal ftpUri As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal port As String)

        Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ftpUri), FtpWebRequest)

        Try
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)

            Dim bytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload)

            ftpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length
            Using UploadStream As IO.Stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()
                UploadStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                UploadStream.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End Sub
```

my call:
`FtpUploadFile("C:\Users\Desktop\icecream.txt", "sftp.icecream.com", "softserve", "chocolate", "22")`
I also noticed there seem to be a few more options for ftp, but I’m not sure which one is best for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [specify the FTP protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks).  Change your call to `FtpUploadFile("C:\Users\Desktop\icecream.txt", "ftp://sftp.icecream.com", "softserve", "chocolate", "22")`.

You might get another error after fixing this error.  The .Net FTP methods don't support [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), which is the kind of protocol it looks like you're code is trying to connect with.